# В мобильном эмуляторе браузера лишняя ширина

Tags: css, responsive, width

Добрый вечер! Подскажите может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Сделал адаптивную верстку. Проверял через эмулятор мобильных устройств в DevTools Chrome. В настройках ставил Responsive и передвигал ограничитель ширины.  Все было нормально и отображалось хорошо. Но после каких-то манипуляций на определенном разрешении стало отображаться так как на скриншоте. Проверил еще раз через мобильный эмулятор в Firefox, там также появляется лишнее поле справа. Подскажите куда копать чтобы избавиться от такого эффекта в Chrome, раньше его не было. Версия 63.0.3239.108 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)
[image: Лишняя ширина в Chrome DevTools Mobile Emulator]

```css
header {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.contacts-add {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.social-link {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.social-link a {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.social-link .vk {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 13px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 36px;
}

.social-link .instagram {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  left: 67px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 37px;
}

.social-link .youtube {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 117px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 38px;
}

.social-link .facebook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 170px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 44px;
}

.social-link .oddnoklasniki {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 220px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">

<head>

  <title>Драппировка</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body class="home">

  <header id="header">

    <div class="contacts-add">

      <div class="social-link">
        <a class="vk" href="#"></a>
        <a class="instagram" href="#"></a>
        <a class="youtube" href="#"></a>
        <a class="facebook" href="#"></a>
        <a class="oddnoklasniki" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- /social-link -->


    </div>
    <!-- /contacts-add -->

  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Дайте ваш код. Так никто не сможет помочь вам

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение, добавил исходный код

Comment: @WebsF код должен быть представлен как [mcve] прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: Большое спасибо за то, что подтолкнули к правильному способу размещения. Также благодаря принципу минимальности и удаления всего лишнего удалось найти проблемный блок. Виноват был блок .social-link, который содержал потомков  с position: absolute с параметрами для десктопной версии, которые в планшетной уже не влазили и расстягивали область просмотра вправо. Также у элементов body, header не стоит overflow: hidden, поэтому их ничто не ограничивало. Нужно было добавить для блока .social-link display: none в планшетном css. Добавил код с имитацией ошибки, вдруг кому-то пригодится.